# Do you get skill points during Offline split-screen in Resident Evil 6?

Tags: resident-evil-6

I played with a friend in split-screen mode and picked up a few `skill points` items while playing..After an hour or so we quit the game and I checked the Skill Settings. To my surprise, I found that I have `0` Skill Points !!

Is there a specific way to make sure that the `skill points` earned in-game are not lost in split-screen ??
What if my friend got a `skill points` item while he is on a Guest account ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, quitting a game session at any point before you get the "saving" message in the upper left corner along with the typewriter icon animation means you will not retain any changes to your inventory, or skill points collected. This is not the same as when the "checkpoint" message is displayed, checkpoints DO NOT count as saves.

Comment: Is that true even in Splitscreen MP ?

Comment: It's true in all game modes as far as I can tell: split screen, singleplayer, online mp, mercenaries (skill points you collect from slaying enemies will not save if you die or quit before timer runs down).  Only way to make sure what you've done/accomplished is saved is to reach a saving message or play until the stats summary for that game mode. The exception seems to be emblems, progress for breaking emblems saves immediately after breaking one (but nothing else!).